# How can I switch between DIVs properly using fade?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make an example website, but I'm stuck on the part where the buttons can switch which divs fade in and out. Edit: hev1 fixed the main issue, but there was still a couple others, so I fixed the other issues in here.

```
    <script>
        var activebutton = "None";
        var finished = true;
        var buyInfoShown = false;
        var rentInfoShown = false;
        function BuyInfo() {
            if(!buyInfoShown && finished === true) {
                finished = false;
                $("#RentInfo").fadeOut("slow", function() {
                    $("#BuyInfo").fadeIn("slow")
                    buyInfoShown = true;
                    rentInfoShown = false;
                });
            }
            if(buyInfoShown && finished === true) {
                finished = false;
                $("#BuyInfo").fadeOut("slow");
                buyInfoShown = false;
            }
            finished = true;
        }
        function RentInfo() {
            if(!rentInfoShown && finished === true) {
                finished = false;
                $("#BuyInfo").fadeOut("slow", function() {
                    $("#RentInfo").fadeIn("slow");
                    rentInfoShown = true;
                    buyInfoShown = false;
                });
            }
            if(rentInfoShown && finished === true) {
                finished = false;
                $("#RentInfo").fadeOut("slow");
                rentInfoShown = false;
            }
            finished = true;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Please add the HTML.

Comment: added the html.

Comment: Check my answer. Is it what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two different variables to check for the visibility of `#BuyInfo` and `#RentInfo`, respectively.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var activebutton = "None";
    var finished = false;
    var buyInfoShown = false;
    var rentInfoShown = false;
    function BuyInfo() {
        if(!buyInfoShown && finished === false) {
            $("#BuyInfo").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#RentInfo").fadeOut("slow");
            buyInfoShown = true;
            rentInfoShown = false;
            finished = true;
        }
        if(buyInfoShown && finished === false) {
            $("#BuyInfo").fadeOut("slow");
            buyInfoShown = false;
            finished = true;
        }
        finished = false;
    }
    function RentInfo() {
        if(!rentInfoShown && finished === false) {
            $("#RentInfo").fadeIn("slow");
            $("#BuyInfo").fadeOut("slow");
            rentInfoShown = true;
            buyInfoShown = false;
            finished = true;
        }
        if(rentInfoShown && finished === false) {
            $("#RentInfo").fadeOut("slow");
           rentInfoShown = false;
            finished = true;
        }
        finished = false;
    }
</script>
    ...
<div class="main" id="pricing">
        <p style="font-size: 28px;">Pricing</p>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button onclick="BuyInfo()" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">Buy</button>
            <button onclick="RentInfo()" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">Rent</button>
        </div>
        <div id="BuyInfo" style="display: none;">
            <p style="font-size: 18px;">Product</p>
            <p style="font-size: 14px;">Price</p>
            <p>(Image)</p>
            <a href="link"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Buy It Now!</button></a>
            <p style="font-size: 20px;"><b>Use code "code" (without quotes) to get a $20 discount!</b></p>
        </div>
        <div id="RentInfo" style="display: none;">
            <p>Rent Info</p>
        </div>
        <p style="height: 120px;"></p>
        <div style="height: 80px; padding: 80px 0px;">
            <p style="font-size: 12px;">Created by HinkerThinker</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That fixed the main problem, but there were a few other issues that I fixed, which I'll edit into my post for those who have the same problem.